# How does overlayfs handle temp file deallocation?

Tags: docker, containers, filesystems, overlayfs

If I understand properly, Overlayfs handles file deletion in the lower layer by creating a whiteout file in the upper one. Does this mean that no longer necessary tmp files can stay around as garbage even if they are removed from the upper layer? Or is there a specific mechanism that allows those to be freed?

Comment: I think this might help: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-bind-propagation